# I want to implement this format 12345-1234567-1 in regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to implement a pakistan's standard format of cnic number which is like this:`12345-1234567-1`.

But I don't know anything about this. I found the following code for this purpose but it also giving errors in NetBeans.

```
private void idSearchKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    String cnicValidator = idSearch.getText();

    if (cnicValidator.matches("^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$")) {
       idSearch.setEditable(true);
    }
    else {
        idSearch.setEditable(false);
    }        
}
```

Comment: *"it also giving errors in NetBeans"* Is there any chance you can tell us which error this is?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is correct. But it can be condensed to this:

```
^[\\d]{5}-[\\d]{7}-\\d$
```

Where does `idSearch` come from? If its not a final member of the class you can't access it in that way. So make sure `idSearch` is available inside `idSearchKeyPressed`. Also make sure that there are no trailing spaces or something like that. You can do this by calling

```
cnicValidator = cnicValidator.trim();
```

The following example returns `true` for both regex versions.

```
public static void main(String... args){
    String id = "35241-7236284-4";

    System.out.println(id.matches("^[\\d]{5}-[\\d]{7}-\\d$"));
    System.out.println(id.matches("^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$"));
}
```